# Add javascript date to gulp-rev task

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, task

I'm using the gulp-rev plugin to add revision of my app/html page using the Yeomann webapp generator. Workflow for my app -> zip -> revision. But I have problem with replacing the hash generated by gulp-rev plugin.

My gruntfile.js :

```
var rev = require('gulp-rev');
var date = new Date(dateString);
gulp.task('rev', function () {
  return gulp.src('app/*.zip')
    .pipe(rev(new Date().toString()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('deploy/'));
});
```

rev-all use rev-hash to generte the hash

```
'use strict';
var crypto = require('crypto');

module.exports = function (buf) {
    if (!Buffer.isBuffer(buf)) {
        throw new TypeError('Expected a buffer');
    }

    return crypto.createHash('md5').update(buf).digest('hex').slice(0, 10);
};
```

and rev-path to add it to file name

```
      'use strict';
var modifyFilename = require('modify-filename');

module.exports = function (pth, hash) {
    if (arguments.length !== 2) {
        throw new Error('`path` and `hash` required');
    }

    return modifyFilename(pth, function (filename, ext) {
        return filename + '_' + hash + ext;
    });
};

module.exports.revert = function (pth, hash) {
    if (arguments.length !== 2) {
        throw new Error('`path` and `hash` required');
    }

    return modifyFilename(pth, function (filename, ext) {
        return filename.replace(new RegExp('_' + hash + '$'), '') + ext;
    });
};
```

I added (new Date().toString()) to the .pipe(rev()) but it, returns date string object error.

I want to make custom revision string with current date or for  version eg. : v.1.0.0.

Could anyone help me with replace the md5 hex to timestamp in this file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [gulp-replace-task](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace-task), you can set up a pattern and add a timestamp

```
.pipe(replace({
  patterns: [
    {
      match: 'timestamp',
      replacement: new Date().getTime()
    }
  ]
}))
```